# Force tableView edit next cell automatically

Tags: javafx

After typing in the cell, I want the focus
go to the next edit cell automatically.

How to do this ?

I'm using

```
tv.getSelectionModel (). select (row + 1);
tv.edit (row + 1, name); // <--- here not work edition next line
```

But unfortunately it is not working within setOnEditCommit

When it's called by clicking a button that is outside the tableView for example it works. The impression I have is that after setOnEditCommit it puts the last line cell's over.

How to solve this?

Thank's

File of properties

---

```
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;


public class Lin {

        private SimpleStringProperty number;
        private SimpleStringProperty name;


        public Lin(String number, String name ) {
            this.number    = new SimpleStringProperty(number);
            this.name      = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        }


        public SimpleStringProperty numberProperty() {
            return number;
        }

        public String getNumber() {
            return number.getValue();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.getValue();
        }

    }
```

---

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TableTesteEdit extends Application {

    TableView tv = new TableView();
    public ObservableList<Lin> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableColumn<Lin,String> number = new TableColumn("#");
        TableColumn<Lin,String> name = new TableColumn("Name");
        name.setPrefWidth(400);

        number.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("number"));
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("name"));

        name.setCellFactory( TextFieldTableCell.<Lin>forTableColumn() );

        name.setOnEditCommit(
              new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Lin, String>>() {
                  @Override
                  public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Lin, String> t) {

                      int row = t.getTablePosition().getRow();

                      ((Lin)t.getTableView().getItems().get(row)).nameProperty().setValue(t.getNewValue());

                      tv.getSelectionModel().select(row+1);
                      tv.edit(row+1, name);  // <--- here not work edition next line
                  }
            }
        );



        tv.setEditable(true);
        number.setEditable(false);
        name.setEditable(true);

        data.addAll( new Lin("1","AFTER EditCommit go next cell and edit auto"), 
                     new Lin("2","AFTER EditCommit go next cell and edit auto"),
                     new Lin("3","Congratulations !!!")
        );


        tv.getColumns().addAll(number, name);
        tv.setItems(data);


        Scene scene = new Scene(tv, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Edit Auto next Cell");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: no easy/clean way to get it working: there are too many bugs around editing virtualized controls (you might want to browse the bug database ..) - while the biggest stumbling stone is the fact that any modification to the items will cancel any ongoing edit, another is the weird behaviour of edit events, the interaction of both leading to destructive interference ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the baked-in behavior of the table's editing sets the editing cell to null once an edit has been committed. My guess is that this happens after the `onEditCommit` handler has been invoked, so your call to edit the next cell is basically revoked.

A (not very satisfactory) way to fix this is to wrap the call to `tv.edit(...)` in `Platform.runLater(...)`, which has the effect of delegating it to a runnable which is executed after the pending events have been handled:

```
  // tv.edit(row+1, name);
  Platform.runLater(() -> tv.edit(row+1, name));
```

Caveat: As commented below, this method is not reliable, so if this is mission-critical you should not use this approach. If you're just looking for something that is convenient for the user, if not fully reliable, then this may suffice. Unless you're willing to rewrite the table view skin, this may be as good as it gets...

Comment: yeah, dirty all over ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the .requestFocus() method if there is something in the next cell that can pull the focus to it for example if you can only type in 4 letters you could use setOnAction(event->{ if(checkLength()) cell2.requestFocus()});
Good Luck